# Esperar a que termine el proceso de un Hilo(Thread) para poder destruir la actividad

Tags: java, android, hilos

Emmmm, bueno, hola, soy yo de nuevo, bueno e estado investigando por todo internet como solucionar este problema y hasta ahora no se como solucionarlo, la pregunta es simple.
¿Como esperar a que se termine de procesar un hilo para poder destruir la Actividad?

El caso es el siguiente, tengo un SurfaceView, que esta conectado a un Thread ya que desde que se crea el SurfaceView arranca el Hilo y comienza a dibujar todo en pantalla, la cuestión es que es un juego, y como saben el hilo no se puede parar hasta que el juego se cierra ya que el "Personaje" mueve sin parar, el problema es el siguiente, al momento de presionar el botón de "Back" o "Home" automáticamente pasa a destruir el SurfaceView, pero el Thread(Hilo) sigue dibujando, y esto hace que la aplicacion se trabe y salga un mensaje diciendo:

Unfortunately...Has stopped.

Entonces lo que quiero hacer es antes de que se destruya el SurfaceView quiero que detenga el Thread, pero para detenerlo debe esperar hasta que termine de dibujar(O sea termine de dar la vuelta(while) y recien poder ponerlo en false y así que deje de dar vueltas y terminar el proceso.).

Ya eh intentado hacer esto:

```
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
            GameLoop.setRunning(false);
    }
```

O algo mas avanzado como esto:

```
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
            boolean retry = true;
            GameLoop.setRunning(false);
            while (retry) {
                try {
                    GameLoop.join();
                    retry = false;
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
        }
```

Y algo mas avanzado, que es jugar con el ciclo de la vida, antes de pasar al modo "onStop();" que en el modo onPause(); espere a que el hilo termine de dar la vuelta para poder recién pausarlo, y así después pase al modo onStop y después onDestroye, pero esto ocurren milisegundos que no espera a que el hilo se termine y si se cumple la condicion de que el GameLoop se ponga en false, pero el SurfaceView sigue dibujando, y esto hace que la aplicacion se crashee, solo me gustaría saber como hacer que en el método onPause(); espere unos 2 segundos y recién la aplicacion pase al modo onStop();

No les puedo pasar el código por que son como 1500 lineas, espero que me puedan ayudar, gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existen varias formas para detectar la terminación de un Thread, una es detectando la terminación de tu instancia de [Thread](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html), mediante el estado [TERMINATED](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.State.html#TERMINATED) :

```
if(myThread.getState()!=Thread.State.TERMINATED){
//termina la actividad.
    finish();
 }
```

O mediante una interfaz que se dispara al terminar el Thread, incluso por medio de un AsyncTask.

Tu problema principal es que deseas cerrar la actividad cuando existe un Thread que esta modificando la UI, propongo como solucion llamar el método `interrupt()` de tu instancia de Thread para obligar a detener el Thread:

### myThread.interrupt()

Como complemento a la respuesta, en cuanto a esto que deseas:

> onPause(); espere unos 2 segundos y recién la aplicación pase al modo
>   onStop();

Esperar, no se puede realizar ya que estarías modificando el ciclo de vida natural de la Actividad.

Comment: Muchaaaas gracias, me ayudaste mucho, ya pude solucionarlo, solo tuve que añadir en el ciclo de la vida en el método "onPause()" añadir el interrupt(); y con eso se soluciono, en serio me has salvado la vida

Comment: Excellente Kevin! Me da gusto lo hayas logrado, Saludos!.